# How to apply css rule to entire page selector class ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

I want to apply a specific css class on the entire ionic2 selector class, rather than on the ion-content.

For example I have a page with a selector:

```
selector: 'home-page'
```

Now I want to toggle a css rule ( toggle a class 'resize-page' ) via TS function inside the ionic2 page. So each time I push the button it adds or toggles this class to the entire page selector.

Comment: Can you show the `ts` code and `html` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<ion-content [ngClass]="getClass()">

</ion- content>
```

And in your .ts file:

```
buttonClickedTimes = 0;
getClass(): string {
    // based on how many times the button is clicked
    // return 'class-1' or 'class-2' 
    this.buttonClickedTimes % 2 == 0 ? 'class-1' : 'class-2';
}

clickButton(): void {
    this.buttonClickedTimes ++;
}
```

OR, as [iWork](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944708/iw%C3%B6rk) suggested in a comment:

```
<ion-content [class]="buttonClickedTimes%2 === 0 ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'"></ion-content>
```

Comment: I'd rather use ```<ion-content [class]="buttonClickedTimes%2 === 0 ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'"></ion-content>```, since I wouldn't want my TS to know the class-name. That belongs to the template.

Comment: Sure, that will also work. I just added a more detailed version in case a more business-login approach is needed.

Comment: I think this will apply the class only to the ion-content. But it will not include the header or footer elements. My question was on how to apply class over the whole page selector. 
I want to apply a scale css attribute, and for that case, I want to apply over the whole page, not just the ion-content.

Comment: I think it should work by adding a `host` property to the `@Component` decorator. See https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-alpha.31/angular2.angular2/Directive/host.html